# Backbone.js, updating rating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm making a small website for school, it's an image based gallery where you can vote and comment.
At the moment they're all on one page and all have a rating form.

So at the moment the default rating is working, but I cant update it (I frankly don't know how)
Here's how it looks now

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDYfr.png

The user is supposed to enter a rating, and then it should show the new value of the rating.

I'm pretty close since when I rate the first image 3; I get: (in my console)

"c1, 3"

And when I rate the 4th image 5, I get:

"c4, 5"

etc.

Now how do I update the default rating?
(default ratings are set in my collection)

Example code of image in collection

```
{image: "images/gifs/water.gif", rating: 5, comments: "Love the detail in this one!", title:"Water", category:"Nature"}
```

Here's how it's in my view:

```
gifs_html += '<td>' + "<span class=\"stars\">" + gifs[gif].get("rating") + ".0</span>" + "\n" + "<form data-id=\"" + gifs[gif].cid  + "\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" size=\"5\" value=\"\"/>" + "\n" + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Rate\">" + "<input type =\"hidden\" name=\"cid\" value=\"" + gifs[gif].cid + "\"> </form>" + '</td>';
```

Then I'm giving this jquery function (to update the star image)

```
$('span.stars').stars();
```

and this event

```
                events:{
                'submit form':function(ev){
                    var $form = $(ev.currentTarget);

                    var id = $form.data("id");
                    var rating = $("input[name=amount]", $form).val();
                    console.log(id + ", " + rating);
                    return false;
                }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with default rating? Do you mean the arithmetic mean which is the sum of all the ratings divided by number of votes?

Comment: I mean the rating I hardcoded assigned as here
`{image: "images/gifs/water.gif", rating: 5, c etc..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view where you are setting that 'submit form' event it's a Collection View you have to do something like this:

```
this.collection.get(id).set("rating", rating);
```

If it would be a Model View:

```
this.model.set("rating", rating);
```

Cheers.